# CSS: max-width won't wrap around an absolute container

Tags: html, css

I've been playing with this one for hours, with no success.

I have a top menu with submenus (that contains a popup menu).

In one of my popup menus, i need the container to be maximum 170 pixels width and all of the items to wrap around that width. For some reason they don't wrap up.

I've reproduced the exact menu in a fiddle. Notice the submenu `COUNTRY`. It contains a popup with flags, but they don't wrap around

https://jsfiddle.net/h81y2t0L/

I've added attributes like a width, a min-width, a white-space with no success

```
.flagMenu {
  max-width: 170px;
  /* white-space: normal; */
}

.flagMenu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

How do i wrap around the flags in the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To wrap the inline-blocks you need to define a container width - but since you don't want an exact width, use `width: max-content;` That way the width will be equal to the width of the content but the max-width will stop it from growing further.

```
.flagMenu {
  max-width: 170px;
  white-space: normal;
  width: max-content;
}
```

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h81y2t0L/1/)

Comment: i had no idea max-content existed. Thanks

Comment: @Marco `min-`/`max-`/`fit-content` have been around for years, and should've been standard years ago. Make sure you use the prefixes: `-webkit-` and `-moz-` for Safari and Firefox. The crap M$ browsers don't support it (no surprise there).

Comment: oh, that sucks. Doesn't work in Edge. I guess put `width: 170px;` right above it as fallback for M$.